# Hard drive "Do not remove" indicator on, but all drives reporting ok

Tags: hard-drive, hp, hp-proliant

We've got a Proliant DL360 Gen 8 with an odd issue. It has four hard drives installed ([this type](https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c03245333#N10771)). I believe it's set up as two RAID 1 pairs. This is an ESXi host that I can't easily shut down, and it's located in a remote office with limited on-site technical expertise. We don't have iLO set up.

One of the hard drives in the server has in the last couple of weeks begun displaying its "Do Not Remove" indicator, which typically means its RAID group is degraded. Problem is, all four drives have a solid green status indicator. Are there any other situations in which a drive's Do Not Remove indicator would be illuminated?

Comment: Are you relying solely on the lights to figure out what is wrong? Or have you opened the array admin software to check things out?

Comment: @longneck Which array admin software are you referring to? Just curious, as I didn't think I actually had any options the way the server is configured.

Comment: Are you familiar with the ILO interface of the server?

Comment: @ewwhite We don't have iLO set up.

Comment: LO management is an essential feature for a remote host. Not setting it up isn't smart.

Comment: @Zac67 I agree, but that doesn't change the situation.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't already have it, you need to install the HPE Smart Storage Administrator software for VMWare. This will allow you to see more detail about the condition of your storage configuration.

See https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?swItemId=MTX_69105a0095f445bbb9eb752643

Comment: Is this supposed to be installed on the server itself? Because this is a VMWare ESXi host, so I can't install general software on it.

Comment: Yes. The `ssacli`shell command provides control over the RAID controller - configure, check logs, ...

Comment: Yes, this is installed on the ESXi host. The page I linked provides install instructions. This is the right way to manage SmartArray controllers on ESXi hosts.